# Prevent component from rendering input attributes

Tags: canjs

I have a `my-tag` component that simply renders a title:

#### html

```
<div id="content"></div>

<script id="main-template" type="text/mustache">
    <my-tag title="This is the title"></my-tag>
</script>
```

#### javascript

```
var Component = can.Component.extend({
    tag: 'my-tag',
    template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>',
    viewModel: {
        title: '@'
    }
});

$('#content').html(can.view('main-template', {}));
```

#### output

```
<div id="content">
    <my-tag title="This is the title">
        <h1>This is the title</h1>
    </my-tag>
</div>
```

I would like to have the output as follows:

```
<div id="content">
    <my-tag>
        <h1>This is the title</h1>
    </my-tag>
</div>
```

How can I get the component to *not* render the `title` attribute in `my-tag`?

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EbenRoux/xc94swxk/).

Comment: Why do you want to remove the title?  CanJS keeps them around to enable changes to bindings via direct attribute manipulation. (they also are nice for debugging, I can see what the component was passed easier).

Comment: Well, the 'title' as used in this case isn't too much of a concern even though it does appear as though more than the required number of bindings may be set up.  I was thinking more in the line of an 'id' when using *that* as the id of an inner element although as far as I understand there is also some restriction around `id, `class`, and some other attribute that I cannot recall right now.

Comment: On second thought, I am probably going about this the wrong way.  I could pass some value across and render the id on the inner element anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent it from rendering, however, you might be able to remove it after the component is created like:

```
var Component = can.Component.extend({
    tag: 'my-tag',
    template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>',
    viewModel: {
        title: '@'
    },
    events: {
      init: function(){
        this.element.removeAttr("title");
      }
    }
});
```

Also, if you are starting a new CanJS project, I'd encourage you to switch to `can.stache` as that will be the default templating engine in 3.0. It's highly compatible with can.mustache.

Comment: I was considering using stache given what I had read but it seems as though there may be an issue when using components as they are somehow tightly coupled to mustache rendering for now.  If I am mistaken I can have a closer look :)

Comment: Custom elements work perfectly fine in stache.  The view-bindings look a bit different though.